# What SQL JOIN to use to get unique values across tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Lets say I have 2 tables T1 and T2. I need all values from table T1 that does not exist in table T2. How would that SQL look like?

```
T1:         T2:
T1.ID       T2.ID   
T1.Value    T2.T1ID 
T1.Date     T2.Value
```

Comment: you can write normal join query and then use array_unique to remove duplicate values

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Please give some example data and show what result you would like for this data. Consider creating a demo on  http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: @sivagopal That assumes the use of PHP and will fetch an unnecessary amount of data. Bad advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need all values from table T1 that does not exist in table T2. How would that SQL look like?

You mean you need every `T1.Value` that does not match any `T2.Value`?

If so, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE Value NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM T2)
```

MySQL, however, may not be very good at finding optimal plan for executing this query, so if your **measurements** show a performance problem, try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.Value = T2.Value
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Note the DISTINCT clause, which ensures T1 rows are not "multiplied" by the JOIN.

Or even like this, if you *only* care about `T1.Value`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.Value
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what a `LEFT JOIN` is for. In your case:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID=T2.T1ID
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Recommended reaading: [MySQL JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you need something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.t1id)
```

This will return all records in t1 that do not have any matching records in t2 (t1.id = t2.t1id).